# Can we use "include?" in this situation?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I just want to know whether i can use include? method in this place or not, Is it appropriate to use include method here?

I have a Users table and a Roles table, there are many_to_many relation in b/w user & role.
Now i want to check the role of the user.
something like this:

**1. Using include**

This is returning false whereas i am expecting true, coz that user having admin role.

```
def isadmin(user)
    user.roles.include?("admin")
end
```

**2. Without include**

This solution is working for me but i want to know about include.

```
def isadmin(user)
    for role in user.roles
      if role.name == "admin"
        return true
      end
    end
    false
end
```

**Note:** I have this role assigned to the user for whom i am checking the role.

```
#<Role id: 1, name: "admin", created_at: "2014-12-07 07:45:42", updated_at: "2014-12-07 07:45:42">
```

Comment: The only reason the second one is working for you is coincidence.

Comment: The reason the first one *isn't* working is because "admin" is not a `Role`, it's a string.

Comment: Can't we check string using include ?

Comment: You could do `user.roles.include?(Role.find_by_name("admin"))` or `user.roles.map(&:name).include?("admin")`

Answer (score 0):

The first one isn't working because you're comparing an array of `role` objects to a string. You want something like this:

`user.roles.map(&:name).include?('admin')`